# SQL Function Error

Tags: sql, sql-server, function, parameters

I have a SQL Function like this;

```
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[fngcodeme]
(
    @HESAP INT, @DOV INT, @TEKLIF VARCHAR(10)
)
RETURNS FLOAT

AS
BEGIN

DECLARE @Result float

SET @Result = (SELECT SUM(TUTAR)
    FROM YAZ..MARDATA.M_GHAREKET
    WHERE TEMEL_HESAP = @HESAP
    AND DOVIZ_KOD = @DOV
    AND REF_KOD = 'GC'
    AND BACAK_GRUP = 'PERT'
    AND ISL_KOD = 1
    AND ACIKLAMA LIKE '% + @TEKLIF + %''')


RETURN @Result

END
```

This is perfectly work.

This `SQL` also work. Result is `18587.73`

```
SELECT SUM(TUTAR)
 FROM YAZ..MARDATA.M_GHAREKET
 WHERE TEMEL_HESAP = 1252
 AND DOVIZ_KOD = 21
 AND REF_KOD = 'GC'
 AND BACAK_GRUP = 'PERT'
 AND ISL_KOD = 1
 AND ACIKLAMA LIKE '%S08-2/334%'
```

But when i want to start this function with parameters in `SQL Server`;

```
 SELECT dbo.fngcodeme(1252, 21, 'S08-2/334')
```

Result is getting `NULL`.

I don't understand what i'm doing wrong..!

Anyone idea??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Need to to fix the @TEKLIF filter

```
AND ACIKLAMA LIKE '%' + @TEKLIF + '%'
```

You are actually searching for this value currently

```
% + @TEKLIF + %'
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 AND ACIKLAMA LIKE '% + @TEKLIF + %''')
```

Should read

```
  AND ACIKLAMA LIKE '''%' + @TEKLIF + '%''')
```